# Is there a more elegant way to write this transform operation?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am wondering how to use a transform operation on a groupby dataframe that involves multiple variables.

Here's the code:

```py
data['SqMeterPrice'] = data.Price / data.BuildingArea
data['MeanSqMeterPricePerSuburb'] = data.groupby("Suburb").SqMeterPrice.transform("mean")
```

Is it mandatory / good practice to create the temporary column SqMeterPrice ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to this link on how to ask a question that will get you better responses & good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Can you post some portion of dataframe representing the input & also expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more readable, but not necesary, only need groupby by Series `data["Suburb"]` instead column name `Suburb`:

```
data['MeanSqMeterPricePerSuburb'] = ((data.Price / data.BuildingArea)
                                       .groupby(data["Suburb"])
                                       .transform("mean"))
```

If need use new column only for `transform` is possible create new column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
data['MeanSqMeterPricePerSuburb'] = (data.assign(SqMeterPrice = (data.Price / 
                                                                 data.BuildingArea))
                                         .groupby("Suburb")
                                         .SqMeterPrice.transform("mean"))
```